# VB Application Search MySQL Database for Login Credentials

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net

Okay, I posted this question previously but only got half of the answer I require. To put simply I have an application which checks the log-in credentials with those stored in the My SQL Database. The awkward problem I have hear is that I've created it in the way that best suits me, and in a way that's simple for me to understand -- I'm not experienced with programming and self taught. The method I used - though prone to 'injection attacks' and other such dangers is suitable for my application and there's obviously security in my application (CD-Key checks & passwords.)

So, the actual details:

The connection is established successfully and I'm able to manipulate the data from the application.

Connection Code:

```
Public Sub conecDB()
    'This is called upon program start.
    Dim connectionString As String = SQLLoginIn.serveriptxt.Text    'This is the server IP/Server name.  If server is intalled on your local machine, your IP should be 127.0.0.1 or you may use localhost
    Dim strDbase As String = SQLLoginIn.databasenametxt.Text  'Database name
    Dim strUser As String = SQLLoginIn.databaseusertxt.Text    'Database user
    Dim strPass As String = "CENSORED"     'Database password

    If connDB.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then connDB.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & connectionString.Trim & ";Initial Catalog=" & strDbase.Trim & ";MultipleActiveResultSets=False;User ID=" & strUser.Trim & ";Password=" & strPass
    If connDB.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then connDB.Open()
End Sub
```

That works great, for what I need it to do.

I add the records (of a separate table) to a listview in my program called `lvRec`

Code:

```
Public Sub dispRec(ByVal PstrSQL As String)
        'This is called once the connection is established.
        frmMain.lvRec.Items.Clear()

    With comDB
        .CommandText = PstrSQL
        rdDB = .ExecuteReader
    End With
    Do While rdDB.Read
        Item = frmMain.lvRec.Items.Add(rdDB!Members_ID.ToString)
        Item.SubItems.Add(rdDB!Gamer_Tag.ToString.Trim)
        'And a bunch of more
        Item.SubItems.Add(rdDB!Games_Owned.ToString.Trim)
        My.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    rdDB.Close()
End Sub
```

So now that you've seen how I'm working with SQL you're probably screaming "That's not how you do it!", but as I sayed, it works for me :) The problem occurs when I want to varifiy the user with their own Username & Password stored on a different Table called `Logins`.

I know I need to/can use the below code to query the users input with the log-in credentials in the `Logins` table, but I don't know how to return anything use-able like a Boolean result or something similar. I simply want to know if the credentials teh user entered are correct, so a TRUE for it existing would be great.

The SQL Query:

```
SQL = "Select * from logins " & _
  "where Name like '%" & Me.Usernametxt.Text.Trim & _
  "%' AND Passkey LIKE '" & Me.Passwordtxt.Text.Trim  & "'"
```

I know this is a lot of detail for such a simple question but I needed people to understand the way I've went around this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` unless you actually want fuzzy matching - and definitely not on a password - You know entering a password of `%` will work for any account, right? Also, while I understand you want to do it "your way" and everyone has their own style, that's no excuse for doing it wrong. If you don't care about security, do away with passwords entirely. If you care even a little, this is inadequate.

Comment: @Basic I've reviewed my way of doing it and have concluded it's terrible. I'll be learning and implementing the proper way now; It'll end up easier for me that way anyway. And Thanks for pointing out the '%' issue, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I wrote a couple of comments to point you in the right direction but decided a non-answer might be more helpful. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the general command on how to return a singular results from a SQL command:

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim success As Object

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logins " & _
                  "WHERE Name = @Name " & _
                  "AND Passkey = @Passkey"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",Me.Usernametxt.Text.Trim)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passkey",Me.Passwordtxt.Text.Trim)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

success = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but to help you get started with authentication in a more robust fashion...

[Please bear in mind that you should *never* take an SO answer as gospel as all of us make mistakes and security is a very difficult topic to do right even for the professionals...]

The process you want to follow is something like the following (in pseudocode)

```
UserRecords = ExecuteSql("SELECT UserID, PasswordHash, Salt, IsEnabled FROM Users WHERE Username = '<Blah>'")

If UserRecords.Count <> 1
    'Login Failed
End If

Dim UserRecord = UserRecords.First

If Hash(PasswordEnteredByUser & UserRecord.Salt) <> UserRecord.PasswordHash
    'Login Failed
End If

If UserRecord.IsEnabled <> True
    'Login Failed
End If

' Login was successful, continue as planned
```

A hashing function works by taking an input eg `MyPassword!` and converting it to something else eg `AB0653AAAF330`. Think of it as a sausage maker - you put a pig in one end and get a sausage out the other end. It's impossible to turn a sausage back into a pig. In theory, however, putting the same pig in twice will produce the same sausage. By storing the sausage, not the pig a database breach [won't reveal users passwords](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/11/hack-of-cupid-media-dating-website-exposes-42-million-plaintext-passwords/)

The "Salt" comes in to play when your database is breached. Imagine two users picked the same password. You know bob's password is `MyPassword!` and you can see it's stored as `AB0653AAAF330`. Anyone else with a password hash of `AB0653AAAF330` has the same password - meaning multiple accounts could be breached at once.

If, on the other hand, there is a random string which is user-specific and appended to their password pre-hashing, Bob's password is treated as `MyPassword!AAAAAAAAA` which (say) hashes to `099DEF3333445` and Jane's (identical) password is treated as `MyPassword!BBBBBBBBB`which (say) hashes to `AAAAE1234400`.

In short, knowing Bob's password won't tell you that Jane has the same one.

This is still a hideously incomplete example. There are many other things to consider (eg the hashing algorithm. MD5 hashing is considered weak, bcrypt is intentionally computationally expensive to make brute-forcing more difficult, etc) but hopefully it will give you a rough idea to get you started.

You also want to make authentication binary - success or failure. If you tell the user "That username is invalid" (as opposed to a simple "Login Failed") as a help to them, they can use the feature to determine valid usernames by repetition.

I wholeheartedly recommend you read [this article](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) on how a company was compromised via SQL injection - once you know how it works in detail, you'll be able to see the pitfalls...

Another feature to consider is a failed login "window" - a sliding period of time in which a certain number of failed logins is allowed before that account becomes locked (possibly temporarily). This means brute-forcing passwords becomes impractical. This is usually handled by recording a `FailedLoginAttempts` and a `FailedLoginTimeout` against the user account. If a login fails, set the Timeout to now + 30 mins. If attempts > some threshold and the timeout hasn't expired, lock the account. If the login fails, extend the timeout. You get the idea.

Finally, if you're *really* security-conscious, when a user logs in successfully, tell them when they last logged in. If someone's been on holiday for a week and sees "Your last login was yesterday" they know instantly that something's wrong.

All the best.